# How to perform cumulative division in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I know that there would be more questions for cumulative division on stackoverflow. But my question is different from these questions.

Actually I want to do comulative division like we use comulative sum (cumsum) and comulative product(cumprod) in python. But there is no cumulative division function in python. If you have any alternative for this then tell me.

**Problem:-**
Below is the dataframe (DF) in which I need to create Discount column and do cumulative division in (discount) column.

DF:-

```
Rates        Discount 
0.000028745455   1/(1+Rates)
0.000028745455   Discount[0]/(1+Rates)
0.000028745455   Discount[1]/(1+Rates)
0.000028745455   Discount[2]/(1+Rates)
0.000028745455   Discount[3]/(1+Rates)
0.000028745455   Discount[4]/(1+Rates)
0.000028745455   Discount[5]/(1+Rates)
```

Result:-

```
Rates              Discount 
0.000028745455   0.999971255
0.000028745455   0.999942512
0.000028745455   0.999913769
0.000028745455   0.999885026
0.000028745455   0.999856285
0.000028745455   0.999827545
0.000028745455   0.999798805
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `cumprod`

```
df['out'] = (1/(df.Rates + 1)).cumprod()
Out[538]: 
0    0.999971
1    0.999943
2    0.999914
3    0.999885
4    0.999856
5    0.999828
6    0.999799
Name: Rates, dtype: float64
```

> Discount[1] = Discount[0]/(1+Rates) = 1 / (1+Rates)^2

Comment: Hi BENY, I got my desired output. Thanks. Could you please explain this how did you do this using cumprod ()

Comment: @Yaser Discount[1] = Discount[0]/(1+Rates) = 1 / (1+Rates)^2  this is why  cumprod work ~